# Saving navigational data as well when saving the entity

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

Given the following models (I'm using EF Core):

```
public class Person {
   public Person(){
         PhoneNumbers = new HashSet<PhoneNumber>();
   }
   public int Id {get; set;}
   public String Name {get; set;}
   public virtual ICollection<PhoneNumber> PhoneNumbers { get; set; }
}
public class PhoneNumber {
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public String Number {get; set;}
    public int PersonId {get; set;}
}
```

When try to add a new `Person` with many new `PhoneNumbers` using the following approach:

```
 Person person = new Person {Name = "Jimmy"};
 foreach(var phone in Phone_Number_In_Posted_Form){
     person.PhoneNumbers.Add(new PhoneNumber {Number = phone});
 }
 Db.Entity<Person>(person).State = EntityState.Added;
 Db.SaveChanges();
```

Entity framework does not automatically associate the `Id` (Auto Increment) generated to the `PhoneNumbers` (the navigational property) and for that reason the `PhoneNumbers` is not saved by SQL Server. Although this can be worked around through getting the generated `Id` and run another loop to associate it manually, I'd like to know if there is any standard solution built into Entity Framework that can work more effectively.

Comment: What's the PK of `PhoneNumber` entity (table)? Also do you have any fluent configuration not shown here?

Comment: @IvanStoev: it is an auto increment integer called 'id'. I edited the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Entity framework does not automatically associate the Id (Auto Increment) generated to the `PhoneNumbers` (the navigational property) and for that reason the `PhoneNumbers` is not saved by SQL Server

The reason is different. It's because setting the [`State`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.changetracking.entityentry#Microsoft_EntityFrameworkCore_ChangeTracking_EntityEntry_State) property does *not* cascade (does *not* apply recursively to the related data), hence is not a replacement of the corresponding `DbContext` / `DbSet` methods.

In you your case, instead of setting the `State` to `Added` you should call the `Add` method:

```
Person person = new Person {Name = "Jimmy"};
foreach(var phone in Phone_Number_In_Posted_Form){
    person.PhoneNumbers.Add(new PhoneNumber {Number = phone});
}
Db.Add(person);
Db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: In accordance with MSDN: We must be able to add entities using both these ways. `EntityState.Added: the entity is being tracked by the context but does not yet exist in the database` and `Add: A new entity can be added to the context by calling the Add method on DbSet. This puts the entity into the Added state, meaning that it will be inserted into the database the next time that SaveChanges is called.`. So what exactly would be the difference? Does the `Add` method do anything other than setting the entity state to added as well?

Comment: That was prior EF Core (EF6). In EF Core it's different, and the difference is what happens with related data (through navigation properties). Setting the state does just that, while `Add`, `Remove` additionally do the same with the related entities.